# getattr with custom string class

Tags: python, python-3.x, getattr

I have a [custom class](https://github.com/ZhiyuanChen/CHANfiG/blob/master/chanfig/variable.py) for wrapping immutable object to mutable objects.

It works fine for most operations, e.g., "+=", f-string, etc.

However, when I try to call `getattr(obj, Variable("attr"))`, it always raises `TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string`. I have hacked `__class__` method to make it believes `is instance(Variable("attr"), str) = True`. How can I solve this issue?

MWE:

```py
class Variable:
    def __init__(self, value) -> None:
        self.storage = [value]

    @property  # type: ignore
    def __class__(self) -> type:
        return self.value.__class__

    @property
    def value(self) -> Any:
        return self.storage[0]

    @value.setter
    def value(self, value) -> None:
        self.storage[0] = self._get_value(value)

    def get(self) -> Any:
        return self.value

    def set(self, value) -> None:
        self.value = value
```

Comment: Do you understand that this is a bad idea?

Comment: Mutable objects for {str, int, float} is crucial to a config system. As values with the same meaning must be consistent at all time. And ideally, they should be identical to what they were.
So, I do not understand why this is a bad idea, though I hate to hack this way. @TimRoberts

Comment: Can you explain more what the end goal of this is?

Comment: And yet there are dozens of config systems that do not require this kind of hackery.  Config systems usually pull their items from some central config object, where the config items can be changed/replaced without requiring them to be mutable.  Users expect strings to work like standard strings.

Comment: for example, config.dataset.tokenizer = config.model.tokenizer = "TokenizerA". If config.dataset.tokenizer is set to TokenizerB, config.model.tokenizer should be to TokenizerB changed automatically. @blueteeth

Comment: But some config values are synced, how to make the synced values change automatically when we change one value? @TimRoberts

Comment: Synced to what?

Comment: Synced to other values. Like my examples for blueteeth.

Comment: I think you should rethink how the config is structured. Rather than replicating values, you could just have one value, and an implicit hierarchy. In your example you could have `config.tokenizer` actually set, but when you query any `config.*.tokenizer` you get that value.

Comment: Unfortunately this will not work, synced values are only a small portion, for example, dropout appears very often but there values are often different. Besides, the reason why we need multiple values with the same meaning is to allow calling function by func(**config.func). Hacking getattr/getitem wouldn’t work.